# Scala: Is there a way where type aliases can be treated as distinct from the type that they alias?

Tags: scala, casting, implicit-conversion, typechecking

Given the following example: I want to truncate a String to meet certain length constraints, e.g. compatibility with SQL types.

```
type varchar8 = String

implicit def str2Varchar8(str: String): varchar8 = str.take(8)

val a: varchar8 = "abcdefghi"

// wanted: "abcdefgh", actual result:
a: varchar8 = abcdefghi
```

It seems like the compiler does not distinguish between the two types.

Given a type alias `type A = String`, What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. to avoid runtime allocation (i.e. a wrapper class)
2. the ability to apply assertions/transformations only when mapping from `String` to the type alias `A`. i.e. avoid further assertions/transformations when working directly with the type alias `A` as input

Validation example:

```
type NotNullA = A

def method(a: A) = if(a != null)
    _method(a: NotNullA) // explicit typing
  else
    ???

// "a" at runtime is a String but we consider it validated, instead relying on the type system
protected def _method(a: NotNullA) = ???
protected def _otherMethod(a: NotNullA) = ???
```

Is there a way where type aliases can be treated as separate from the type that they alias - and thus make implicit conversions and type checking between them possible? Is there some other encoding/technique that does the job?

Side: I seem to recall a point where the two **were** separate and the type and alias were distinct (not relating to a type arity issue). My previous code went something like:

```
type FieldAType = Int

// and in a different class
def method(a: FieldAType) = ???

val b: FieldAType = 1
method(b) // worked

val c: Int = 1
method(c) // compiler error
method(c: FieldAType) // worked
```

However, I've not been able to reproduce this issue (possibly due to an older Scala version - currently using 2.11.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kindly advise you to take a look at [softwaremill.scala-common.tagging](https://index.scala-lang.org/softwaremill/scala-common/tagging/2.1.0) library.

- No runtime overhead
- A reliable way to protect your type

Just add import and define your tagged type:

```
import com.softwaremill.tagging._

type EvenTag
type EvenInt = Int @@ EvenTag

object EvenInt {
  def fromInt(i: Int): Option[EvenInt] =
    if (i % 2 == 0) Some(i.taggedWith[EvenTag]) else None
}

def printEvenInt(evenInt: EvenInt): Unit = println(evenInt)

EvenInt.fromInt(2).foreach(printEvenInt)

val evenInt: EvenInt = 2 // Doesn't compile
printEvenInt(2) // Doesn't compile
```

How we can hack it?

```
val evenInt: EvenInt = 1.taggedWith[EvenTag]
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The use case I envision for use in protected code, and making sure there are no type errors/bugs. Seems it can support polymorphism also: "You can only use x: T @@ U when an instance of type T @@ V is expected when U is a subtype of V (U <: V)" and "Similar implementations are also available in Shapeless and Scalaz."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible. Aliases are just that, an additional name. Purely for readability.

However, you can do this with [value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html). They are properly different types and so you can handle them differently in your code. But most of the time the compiler is able to avoid actually allocating the wrapper object - the linked page has more info about what the exceptions to this are.

Comment: There are a long list of exceptions and limitations, but I like the simplicity :) Likely the type safety, conversion support etc. would trump a potential object allocation cost.

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature that's likely to be implemented in Scala 3: `opaque type`s.

They literally solve the problem you describe: being able to distinguish type aliases with ordinary types based on their name and not on their real underlying type.

Have a look at [the official proposal](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/opaque-types.html).